# Non-interactive authentication and authorization in Azure AD B2C

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Is it possible for AD B2C to be utilized for non-interactive authentication. i.e. I want to pass-in a username (email-id)/password and be authenticated into application (not API backend but a web application bypassing a login flow - basically auto-login that user interaction with a user/passwords and redirect to a resource)

I have used [ROPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy?tabs=app-reg-ga&pivots=b2c-user-flow) for backend API could that be utilized or is there any other way.

Can we get access and id token from a call similar to:

```
https://<tenant-name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/<policy-name>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=<application-ID>
&nonce=anyRandomValue
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&scope=<application-ID-URI>/<scope-name>
&response_type=code
```

without the interactive flow and providing a redirectURL.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the **same flow** for web application too in getting access and id tokens non-interactively.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I registered one web application in my B2C tenant and added Redirect URI in **`Web`** platform like below:

[image]

In Manifest, make sure to enable **implicit flow** like below:

[image]

I exposed one API and granted that **API permission** to `WebApp` like below:

[image]

Now, I created one **resource owner user flow** as below:

[image]

I got both  **access** and **id tokens** successfully via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://b2ctenantname.b2clogin.com/b2ctenantname.onmicrosoft.com/<ROPC_policyname>/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id:<App_ID>
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
grant_type:password
username: <UPN_of_B2C user> 
password:xxxxxxxxxxxx
scope:openid https://b2ctenantname.onmicrosoft.com/appID/Custom.Scope
response_type:token id_token
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I decoded the above access token, I got **`scp`** claim successfully with custom scope as below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I want to be able to use this access token to allow automatic login to the UI screens (not be challenged with AD B2C login. Call to API I have currently with my ROPC flow, is it possible to use this access_token to continue to UI flow (redirect_url) . Web page 1 --> b2c../oauth2/v2.0/token --> access_token --> web app 2 (it uses ad b2c) but since has access_token should bypass the login screen. Appreciate any pointers.